# How to setup different server environments for CMS's MySQL credentials

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, concrete5

We have a local MAMP environment plus development and production servers which all use different MySQL credentials.

We're trying to setup a statement in our CMS's config.php file that uses the correct credentials based on the environment.

The statement we currently have looks like this:

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'domain.com') { // PRODUCTION Server
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'db-user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db-password');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'db-name');
      } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'domain.devserver.com') { // DEV Server
        define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
        define('DB_USERNAME', 'db-user');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db-password');
        define('DB_DATABASE', 'db-name');
      } else { // MAMP
        define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
        define('DB_USERNAME', 'db-user');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db-password');
        define('DB_DATABASE', 'db-name');
      }
?>
```

But only the last set of credentials (MAMP) ever gets used - is there a way to do this in a single php file?

Other stuff we've found involves the use of several different files and setting an environment variable but we'd like to keep it all within one file or at least within each client's website if that makes sense.

We know very little php - any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Comment: This is pretty basic PHP. There's not a lot of room for "weird issues". It's pretty clear that the HTTP_HOST variable isn't matching either domain.com or domain.devserver.com. add a `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])` at the top and run it a few times on the target servers. I'll guarantee that when it doesn't work, the output will be something different (maybe like www.domain.com).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code above, but perhaps a switch will make it behave properly.

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
case "domain.com":
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'db-user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db-password');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'db-name');
    break;
case "domain.devserver.com":
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'db-user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db-password');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'db-name');
    break;
default:
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'db-user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db-password');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'db-name');
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps - yes, I've actually tried both and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I'm not sure if there's anything on the server that would prevent either working but I've triple checked the mysql credentials so I'm pretty sure that isn't the issue. I'll try the switch version later today as well - thank heaps.

Comment: Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't? does it work for certain servers and not for others?

Comment: Yes, I think we need to track down why it doesn't work sometimes, could be an issue with MySQL user permissions maybe? Cheers

Comment: If it works on more than one server, but not on the third, It's not an issue with the code, it's an issue with a) the server or b) database credentials

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a blog post explaining our approach to this problem:
http://concrete5tricks.com/blog/dev-stage-prod-same-config/